# Sort for specific column by keep other column grouped

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
      CurrencyCodeFrom,
      CurrencyCodeTo, 
      MidRevalRate,
      MultiplierRate,
      RevalRate,
      CurrencyMarketCode,
      Added, 
      Modified, 
      UpdateReason
FROM 
     [InsightWarehouse].[dbo].[DimCurrency] as dc
 INNER  JOIN 
     [InsightWarehouse].[dbo].[FactCurrency] as fc 
     ON fc.CurrencyId = dc.CurrencyId
     AND fc.BusinessDate  = '2018-11-27'
     AND ( CurrencyCodeFrom <> 'KHR' OR CurrencyCodeTo <> 'KHR')
```

**Result**

```
CurrencyCodeFrom    CurrencyCodeTo  MidRevalRate    MultiplierRate  RevalRate   CurrencyMarketCode
THB                 KHR             122.500000000   122.500000000   1.000000000 1
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 10
THB                 KHR             122.500000000   122.500000000   1.000000000 3
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 5
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 7
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 9
USD                 KHR             4035.000000000  4035.000000000  1.000000000 1
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 10
USD                 KHR             4035.000000000  4035.000000000  1.000000000 3
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 5
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 7
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 9
```

I want to sort `CurrencyMarketCode` DESC by keep it group `CurrencyCodeFrom`    `CurrencyCodeTo`

Should be

```
CurrencyCodeFrom    CurrencyCodeTo  MidRevalRate    MultiplierRate  RevalRate   CurrencyMarketCode

THB                 KHR             122.500000000   122.500000000   1.000000000 1
THB                 KHR             122.500000000   122.500000000   1.000000000 3
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 5
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 7
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 9
THB                 KHR             122.750000000   122.750000000   1.000000000 10

USD                 KHR             4035.000000000  4035.000000000  1.000000000 1
USD                 KHR             4035.000000000  4035.000000000  1.000000000 3
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 5
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 7
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 9
USD                 KHR             4047.500000000  4047.500000000  1.000000000 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comment

> I want to sort CurrencyMarketCode DESC by keep it group
>   CurrencyCodeFrom CurrencyCodeTo

doesn't match your result because `CurrencyMarketCode` in your result is in ascending order.

As @ypercube commented, why doesn't a simple

`ORDER BY CurrencyCodeFrom, CurrencyCodeTo, CurrencyMarketCode` solve your problem?

---

```
--demo setup
drop table if exists table1
go
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    [CurrencyCodeFrom] VARCHAR(3)
    ,[CurrencyCodeTo] VARCHAR(3)
    ,[MidRevalRate] DECIMAL(20, 9)
    ,[MultiplierRate] DECIMAL(20, 9)
    ,[RevalRate] DECIMAL(20, 9)
    ,[CurrencyMarketCode] int
    );    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([CurrencyCodeFrom], [CurrencyCodeTo], [MidRevalRate], [MultiplierRate], [RevalRate], [CurrencyMarketCode])
VALUES
    ('THB', 'KHR', 122.500000000, 122.500000000, 1.000000000, 1),
    ('THB', 'KHR', 122.750000000, 122.750000000, 1.000000000, 10),
    ('THB', 'KHR', 122.500000000, 122.500000000, 1.000000000, 3),
    ('THB', 'KHR', 122.750000000, 122.750000000, 1.000000000, 5),
    ('THB', 'KHR', 122.750000000, 122.750000000, 1.000000000, 7),
    ('THB', 'KHR', 122.750000000, 122.750000000, 1.000000000, 9),
    ('USD', 'KHR', 4035.000000000, 4035.000000000, 1.000000000, 1),
    ('USD', 'KHR', 4047.500000000, 4047.500000000, 1.000000000, 10),
    ('USD', 'KHR', 4035.000000000, 4035.000000000, 1.000000000, 3),
    ('USD', 'KHR', 4047.500000000, 4047.500000000, 1.000000000, 5),
    ('USD', 'KHR', 4047.500000000, 4047.500000000, 1.000000000, 7),
    ('USD', 'KHR', 4047.500000000, 4047.500000000, 1.000000000, 9)
;

SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY CurrencyCodeFrom
    ,CurrencyCodeTo
    ,CurrencyMarketCode;
```

---

The results seem your match your desired outcome.

```
| CurrencyCodeFrom | CurrencyCodeTo | MidRevalRate   | MultiplierRate | RevalRate   | CurrencyMarketCode |
|------------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|-------------|--------------------|
| THB              | KHR            | 122.500000000  | 122.500000000  | 1.000000000 | 1                  |
| THB              | KHR            | 122.500000000  | 122.500000000  | 1.000000000 | 3                  |
| THB              | KHR            | 122.750000000  | 122.750000000  | 1.000000000 | 5                  |
| THB              | KHR            | 122.750000000  | 122.750000000  | 1.000000000 | 7                  |
| THB              | KHR            | 122.750000000  | 122.750000000  | 1.000000000 | 9                  |
| THB              | KHR            | 122.750000000  | 122.750000000  | 1.000000000 | 10                 |
| USD              | KHR            | 4035.000000000 | 4035.000000000 | 1.000000000 | 1                  |
| USD              | KHR            | 4035.000000000 | 4035.000000000 | 1.000000000 | 3                  |
| USD              | KHR            | 4047.500000000 | 4047.500000000 | 1.000000000 | 5                  |
| USD              | KHR            | 4047.500000000 | 4047.500000000 | 1.000000000 | 7                  |
| USD              | KHR            | 4047.500000000 | 4047.500000000 | 1.000000000 | 9                  |
| USD              | KHR            | 4047.500000000 | 4047.500000000 | 1.000000000 | 10                 |
```

Comment: We've been discussing this in chat and [ypercubeᵀᴹ suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47800149#47800149) `CurrencyMarketCode` might be a char/varchar column. Although the OP's query doesn't have an ORDER BY, their first output sample looks as though the rows in each group were indeed ordered by the last column and the column was a string data type.

Comment: yes, CurrencyMarketCode  is varchar(5)